# Apple Pay integration on the WEB - setting up the Sandbox environment

Tags: javascript, java, sandbox, braintree, applepay

I want to integrate Apple Pay on my website (so it's a Apple Pay - Web Integration), using the Braintree payment provider, JS as a client side language and Java as a server side language.

I'm having difficulties creating a proper sandbox environment for my Apple Pay implementation Testing. Followed the steps from the Apple docs but it seems they are not accurate:

- Says to create a Merchant Id, one for sandbox and one for production (as far as I can see, at the moment of creating those 2, there's no way of telling that you want to use one for the development environment and the other for the production)
- After that, says to create a Certificate using the Merchant ID created before; if I sign in to my Apple Developer Account, I can see the 'Development' and the 'Production' sections, but when I try to create a sandbox/development certificate, Apple Pay is not available for it, only in the production section (see images below).

  Is there a way to create a Sandbox / Development Apple Pay certificate, or are there any other ways to properly test the Apple Pay integration?

I tried creating a sandbox user tester account from iTunes, but when I tried to login on ITunes on my IPad(compatible with Apple Pay) which I'm using for testing, I get the following error: `ITunes account creation not allowed. This Apple ID cannot be used with the ITunes Store at this time. Please try again later.` I already verified my Apple ID and followed all the steps to activate the account, but without any success.

As I was trying to create Sandbox Apple Pay certificates I mistakenly created 2 for the production environment. Could I revoke them without any problems and create another ones ?

If you integrated Apple Pay on the WEB, I would highly appreciate any help, since I'm having such difficulty in simply setting up my testing environment.

- All certificates are from the below images are created from the 'Development' section of the Apple Developer Account.

First image:
[image: Img1]

Second image:
[image: Img2]

Comment: UPDATE: @zep clarified the sandbox situation: Apple doesn't have an Apple Pay Sandbox Certificate section, instead you must use one of the merchant IDs created in the Apple Developer account for the sandbox certificate creation: the fact that you upload the certificate to the Braintree Sandbox control Panel ensures the distinction between the 2 environments  (+ you need to use a sandbox tester user account for the testing Apple devices).

Comment: UPDATE (ITunes connection problem): You only need to log into ICloud with the sandbox user tester account (which I managed, there seems to be no problem there),but no need for logging in ITunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sandbox Apple Pay Certificate problem**: @zep clarified the sandbox situation: Apple **doesn't have an Apple Pay Sandbox Certificate section**, instead you must use one of the merchant IDs created in the Apple Developer account for the sandbox certificate creation: the fact that you upload the certificate to the **Braintree Sandbox control Panel** ensures the distinction between the 2 environments (+ you **need to use a sandbox tester user account for the testing Apple devices**).

**ITunes connection problem**: You only need to log into **ICloud** with the sandbox user tester account (which I managed, there seems to be no problem there),but no need for logging in ITunes.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact *support@braintreepayments.com*.</sub>

Since Apple doesn't have a "Sandbox" Apple Pay Certificate, the Production Apple Pay Certificate can be used with the Braintree Sandbox environment.

After downloading a CSR from your Braintree Sandbox Control Panel, go to the Apple Developer Center, pick the Apple Pay Merchant ID you're going to use with the Sandbox, and, under the **Production** section, chose **Apple Pay Certificate**. Then upload that certificate to your Braintree Sandbox Control Panel [per these instructions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/configuration/javascript/v3#apple-pay-certificate-request-and-provisioning).

You do not need to log into the iTunes store with your sandbox tester user account on your test device. [You will need to log into iCloud with that tester account](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/configuration/javascript/v3#icloud-account-setup).

Edited to add: the other primary difference between production and sandbox is that [you don't need to host a domain association file on your site for sandbox](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/apple-pay/configuration/javascript/v3#braintree-setup).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, helped me alot :).Just one more question: I will use my localhost server (127.0.0.1:8080) for testing and a server for uat/testing purposes (development.my_site.com). I understand that I must make sure the domain association file is available at the '/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association' path, but since I cannot register the 127.0.0.1:8080 'domain'  port into sandbox, wouldnt therefore be a problem to test in my localhost ?